# Where to place the code to remove a tkinter widget from a window

Tags: python, button, tkinter

To remove a button when using tkinter, I am aware that I am supposed to use `grid_remove`. Where should the command be placed though, and what would the line code that removes it look like?
This is where I created the button.

```
self.button1 = Tkinter.Button(self, text=u"Convert Decimal to Binary", command=lambda: self.OnButtonClick(1))
self.button1.grid(column=1,row=1)
```

Then here is the function I created to determine which button was clicked since I have another just below this one.

```
def OnButtonClick(self, button_id):
    if button_id == 1:
        self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self,textvariable=self.entryVariable)
        self.entry.grid(column=1,row=0,sticky='EW')
        self.entryVariable.set(u"Enter Decimal Number Here")
```

Where would I place the `grid_remove` to get rid of the button, and what would the line of code that removes it look like? I would assume something like this:

```
self.button1 = Tkinter.Button(self, text=u"Convert Decimal to Binary", command=lambda: self.grid_remove(1))
```

But I am not very sure

Comment: grid_remove only removes a widget from view, it doesn't delete the widget. Is that what you want, or are you wanting to actually delete the widget object?

Comment: I want to actually delete the widget, but it seems like this is doing the job. My problem now though, is how to remove(from view) a label.

Comment: If you want to delete the widget, call `.destroy()` on the widget. By calling `grid_remove` you're merely removing it from view. It's still in memory. For a tiny program that's not a big deal, but you don't want to start developing bad habits when you're just getting started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would invoke the `grid_remove` method of `self.button1` like this:

```
self.button1.grid_remove()
```

Below is a sample script to demonstrate:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Button
root = Tk()
def click():
    button.grid_remove()
button = Button(text="click", command=click)
button.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

As far as where to place that line, it is up to you.  It could be inside `OnButtonClick`, inside another method, etc.  Basically, put it wherever you want `self.button1` removed.

I'll assume it is inside `OnButtonClick`, in which case the code would look something like this:

```
def OnButtonClick(self, button_id):
    if button_id == 1:
        self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self,textvariable=self.entryVariable)
        self.entry.grid(column=1,row=0,sticky='EW')
        self.entryVariable.set(u"Enter Decimal Number Here")

        self.button1.grid_remove() # Remove the button
```

Comment: Is there any way we could chat? I have a few more questions, and it would be easier than posting every one of them, if you don't mind of course

Comment: @Dan - It's not that I mind...I have actually never used the chat system here on SO.  So, I am unfamiliar with the way it works.  However, I will give you a very useful reference for Tkinter:  http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/onepage.html  Most of your questions can probably be answered by the information there.